# Conditional Format based on scenario of another Cell

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, max, match, conditional-formatting

Please help change color scale - conditional formatting

B2 = 60 (fixed value)

If B2 = 10 (daily count) then B2 = Green BG

(based on percentage - 1 to 60 )

Min = Green , Mid = Orange, Max and above = Red

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Min = Green , Mid = Orange, Max and above = Red

literally, try:

```
1
30
60
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
1

=(B2-(B3/B2))/1.1

=B2-(B3/B2)
```

[image]